# Debian 9.1 won't boot after dist-upgrade

Tags: debian

So I ran apt-get dist-upgrade, and now my system do not start. I get past the boot menu. Then I see file system check stuff.  Something like:

```
/dev/sda1: clean 34534/324344 files, 23445435/234435466 blocks
```

(Numbers are made up. Did not think the actual numbers were relevant)

This blinks on the screen for a couple of minutes until it stabalizes. I cannot do anything. I've tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+FX 1-12 but no response. Ctrl+Alt+Delete reboots.

It responds to ping and I can login via ssh.

I suspect it has something to do with the graphics drivers, since I have had problems with them in the past. It is a Nvidia card.

In /var/log/kern.log I have this at the end:

```
Nov 10 13:41:56 klutt kernel: [  324.275907] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:41:57 klutt kernel: [  325.164463] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:41:57 klutt kernel: [  325.521060] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:41:58 klutt kernel: [  326.436102] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:41:59 klutt kernel: [  326.781826] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:42:00 klutt kernel: [  327.679554] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:42:00 klutt kernel: [  328.044412] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:42:01 klutt kernel: [  328.891106] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Nov 10 13:42:01 klutt kernel: [  329.238838] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-f5522274-0ae3-8a19-a228-47e2a3b8ac28) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
```

but it goes on for 60 rows or so.

I tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` to `/etc/default/grub`. This made the screen stop flickering, but I still do not get to Gnome login. I can still ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged in via ssh and ran `apt install nvidia-drivers` and it worked.